# Ads on Stack Overflow in Portuguese and Stack Overflow in Spanish are blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, portuguese-stackoverflow

Stack Overflow in Portuguese and Stack Overflow in Spanish have an issue with displaying ads: only a blank space is shown there where an ad should be.

Here is a screenshot for [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), but the same is true for [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

[image: Stack Overflow in Portuguese]

Comment: Are you using an adblocker?

Comment: @Laurel I'm not using AdBlocker. Have you reproduced this bug? To reproduce it you just need to open **any** question of StackOverflow in Portuguese or StackOverflow in Spanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually just a scenario where the page does not collapse automatically if there is no ad available to fill the slot. We're working on getting the page resizing improvement live. Thanks.

Comment: Is this [tag:status-completed] now?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov no it's not. I still see exactly what you described in the bug report. No idea why it is  marked as completed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Recently (maybe week ago or so) the bug seemed to be fixed. But you're right: it has reappeared.

Comment: @Denimjean can you please remove the tag? And poke a dev with sharp stick to "work on getting the page resizing improvement live"? :-)

Comment: No poking devs with sharp sticks over here! I've contacted our team politely to let them know the improvement (which was previously in place - I just got around to updating the tag now), has regressed.

Comment: @Denimjean Fixed? I assume yes, so maybe you should re-add [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: Done. This actually wasn't a regression - it was a separate ad issue where a campaign was not geo targeted correctly.